# Positive derivative at 0

Tags: real-analysis

Proposition: If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$, and $f'(0)>0$, then there exists an open interval $I$ such that $0\in I$ and $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonic.

Proof:
Because $f'$ is continuous at 0, there exists $\delta$ such that $\forall x$ such that $|x|<\delta$, we have $|f'(x)-f'(0)|<f'(0)$ 
$\Leftrightarrow$
$0<f'(x)<2f'(0)$.  So let $I=(-\delta,\delta)$.  Then, $0\in I$ and $\forall x \in I, f'(x)>0$ so $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonic.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$